# Hubot - load environmental variables from a file

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, hubot

setting environmental variables for a Hubot is pretty easy on the production server. However when I want to test the bot locally, I need the env vars inside a file. I already have the file `.env` for env vars that heroku is using for running locally.

But I can't seem to find a way to load env vars inside the Hubot scripts from a file.

Merry Christmas :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay it's possible with hubot-env.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hubot-env

The following command will load the file from a relative path:

`hubot env load --filename=[filename]`.

It previously didn't work for me because I had `HUBOT_ENV_BASE_PATH` set on my mac so the command searched in the wrong folder for the file.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically reference the .env variables? I mean, I dont want a command to be runned each time the hubot bin it's execute again...